# Show div in order when key down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new in coding and sometimes it's hard to find the right term when you search something. I've come a long way but stuck on this piece. Hopefully, someone can help me with the right search term or function.

I've created a responsive grid 2x3 fullscreen, and now when the key is pressed, for example 'a'. A live video will show (opacity from 0 to 1) at the top left box in the grid. 's' key for the second box with another live video and so on for all the six boxes.

But I want to create when one key is pressed, that one video will be played (and it doesn't matter which one of the six) on the top left the box. When a second key is pressed at the same time it will show up in the second box. When a third key is pressed at the same time, it will show up at the third box.

So, the place were it shows depends on the order of the pressed keys. I've tried to search the internet but couldn't find a thing, can someone help me with this? I've created this in Javascript. Thanks!

```
 document.addEventListener("keyup", keyupFunction);
 document.addEventListener("keydown", keydownFunction);

function keydownFunction(e) {
if(e.which == 65){/* a */
    document.getElementById("video1").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio.volume = 1.0;

 } else if (e.which == 83) {/* s */
    document.getElementById("video2").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio2.volume = 1.0;

 } else if (e.which == 68) {/* d */
    document.getElementById("video3").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio3.volume = 1.0;

 } else if (e.which == 70) {/* f */
    document.getElementById("video4").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio4.volume = 1.0;

 } else if (e.which == 71) {/* g */
    document.getElementById("video5").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio5.volume = 1.0;

 } else if (e.which == 72) {/* h */
    document.getElementById("video6").style.opacity = "1";
    myAudio6.volume = 1.0;
```

---

```
    <div class="container-fluid items" id="items">
<div class="row menusrow">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
        <img id="video1" src="http://105.198.227.126:8080/cgi-
bin/camera?">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
        <img id="video2" src="http://24.222.39.230:8082/mjpeg.cgi">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
    <img id="video3" src="http://182.150.46.230:8000/oneshotimage1?
1511867998">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
    <img id="video4" src="http://77.20.35.33:80/mjpg/video.mjpg?
COUNTER">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
    <img id="video5" src="http://122.166.104.28:89/SnapshotJPEG?
Resolution=640x480&amp;amp;Quality=Clarity&amp;amp;1511867938">
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-4 video-container">
    <img id="video6" src="http://117.102.176.209:50000/cgi-bin/camera?resolution=640&amp;amp;quality=1&amp;amp;Language=0&amp;amp;1511873906">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
.video-container {
height: 100%;
position:relative;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;

#video1 {
opacity: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#video2 {
opacity: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

and so on until video6.

Comment: Please add your html + all relevant files so we can help you.

Comment: If 3 keys are pressed, does that mean that 3 videos are playing simultaneously? Or only the 3rd video is playing?

Comment: Yes, all three video's are playing at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this code listens for key pressing and releasing. Pressing increments a counter; releasing decrements that counter. Based on the value `n` of the counter, `n` items are made visible.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 256; i++) keys.push(false);
  var numDown = 0;
  
  var refocus = function() {
    var items = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    
    // Unfocus all
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
      items[i].classList.remove('active');
    
    // Now focus the appropriate amount
    for (var i = 0; i < Math.min(numDown, items.length); i++)
      items[i].classList.add('active');
  };
  
  var items = document.getElementById('items');
  items.onfocus = function() {
    items.classList.add('focused');
  };
  items.onblur = function() {
    items.classList.remove('focused');
  };
  
  items.onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90 || keys[e.keyCode]) return;
    keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    numDown++;
    refocus();
  };
  items.onkeyup = function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 90 || !keys[e.keyCode]) return;
    keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    numDown--;
    refocus();
  };
  
  items.focus();
};
```

```css
.items {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  font-size: 0; /* remove spaces */
  background-color: #ffffff;
}
.item {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.333%; height: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
  background-color: #a0a0a0;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
.item.active {
  background-color: #7070f0;
}
.items.focused > .item {
  border: 1px solid #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<div class="items" id="items" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Please let me know if this is what you were looking for! Also note there's a bit of the extra code making it obvious whether or not the controls are focused (listening for keypresses)

Note this obviously isn't a full answer, but I think it's the piece of the puzzle you need in order to do the rest yourself.

Note that many keyboards will fail to register many simultaneous keypresses! I find that the left side of my keyboard can only register max 4 inputs at a time; same with the right side. I can only register a max of 8 total simultaneous inputs on my keyboard by maxing out both sides.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I mean! But because of the different JS code, I've tried to implement it in my current code. But don't know how.. I've added my CSS and HTML as well.

Comment: Note the `tabindex="-1"` property on the html `items` element. Without it the browser won't let you focus the `items` and receive key input events!

Comment: When I add something to the div class=items (for example my img tag), the whole code wont work... 

From what I see, when a random key is pressed, the state changes of the box to a different color. But is it also possible to show the live stream img tag inside that box?

Comment: I think you should be putting your images not within `[class="items"]`, but within `[class="item"]` - right? Because of the inline-block layout, putting other elements inside `[class="items"]` will cause all the blocks to be pushed downwards.

Comment: Yes, when I place something in class=item class, the whole grid doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Nope, we've worked around it. Thanks again for your input!